# Excel VBA saveas csv but the file output is the wrong format

Tags: excel, csv

HI i am new to vba and am wondering why the file output when i attempted this code just a default file and not csv. I created this code via macro recording. I want to be able to save the file as csv after working on the sheet.  My code is as follows

```
Sub Done()
        Sheets("Test").Select
        Range("A2:M3").Select
        Range("A2:M3").Copy
        Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Sheets("Test").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Save

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
            Application.GetSaveAsFilename, FileFormat:= _
            xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the file as csv try:

```
Sub Done()
    Sheets("Test").Select
    Range("A2:M3").Select
    Range("A2:M3").Copy
    Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Sheets("Test").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\filename.csv", _ 
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Change file path and file name as required.

**EDIT**: Using **SaveAs Dialog Box**
**________________________________________________________________________________**

Try this:

```
Sub Done()
    Sheets("Test").Select
    Range("A2:M3").Select
    Range("A2:M3").Copy
    Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Sheets("Test").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save

    fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="Test", FileFilter:="CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv", Title:="Save As")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname, FileFormat:=xlCSV
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Quick question must i always have the .csv there?

Comment: @Nessuno - If you are talking about `Filename:="C:\filename.csv"` then as long as you mention 'FileFormat:=xlCSV' there's no need to write `.csv`. That means `Filename:="C:\filename"` will also work.

Comment: @Nessuno -Edited code will open SaveAs Dialog box for user to enter path and file name.

Comment: Thanks so much. It is what I needed. =D

Comment: After trying repeatedly to get the appropriate output format, this worked great--thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs`, you need to replace "enter code here" with a filename:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "MyFilename.csv"_
        FileFormat:= xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False _
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Once you have a filename, you can save the file.  You can choose any filename that you want, and simply use that in place of `MyFilename.csv` in this example.

Comment: Thanks i realized my folly after seeing your comment. first time posting. my code doesn't have that "enter code here". editted my post.

Comment: What exactly happens right now?  Are you trying to figure out how to use this code, or how to make it work?

Comment: I was figuring how to get the output file to the correct format (CSV). In my initial code, it ended up being a file. But it's sorted out now. thanks for taking the time and effort to help =)